# filling in text views from shared preferences in a scroll view

Tags: android, list, sharedpreferences, textview

Im a bit stuck on the best way to implement this so here I am.

I have a list of shared preferences with a label and a price. My app, a sort of calculator if you will, I would like to load the shared preferences in this way but stuck on how to implement it properly so ill wrote it down in a very literal way

Load shared preferences "item1"
Load into textView1 if empty
if it is full then try textview2, 
if it is full then try textview3,
etc etc

I would like a function which loads preference 1, attempts to load it into a view and if its full, try the next textview and so on until it finds and empty slot. and then try the next shared preference item

Maybe I'm looking at this wrong but without writing out tons of if/else statements to get the job done, I cant see a way that makes sense.

I've seen somewhere some code to increment the textview numbers in a loop until a case is met but cant seem to recall it anywhere. this would reduce the code a lot if this was implemented properly I'm sure.The app I'm creating will display a list of selected items from another screen,save selected to shared preferences and then load the list on the results screen to give a total based on the sums attached to the items loaded.

I have no actual code to give you as im still prototyping this section and have nothing solid to show you.

any pointers welcome or any nod in the right direction would be handy.

thanks guys

Comment: shouldn't that go into a ListView?

Comment: I was thinking that but that used arrays and as the arrays would have been built dynamically in another screen and then saved to shared preferences, on the result screen Would I still be able to add other items to the array without messing it up? I shall investigate this route and let you guys know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add TextViews dynamiclly through java.

```
public class DynamicAvtivity1 extends Activity {
TextView tv;
EditText et;
Button btn;
LinearLayout ll;
int i;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    i = 1;

    ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(1);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT , LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT , LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    ll.setLayoutParams(lp);

    tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Enter Name");
    tv.setLayoutParams(lp2);
    ll.addView(tv);

    et = new EditText(this);
    et.setHint("Name");
    et.setLayoutParams(lp2);
    ll.addView(et);

    btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setLayoutParams(lp2);
    btn.setText("Add Button");
    btn.setLayoutParams(lp2);
    ll.addView(btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Button b  = new Button(getApplicationContext());
            b.setLayoutParams(lp2);
            b.setText("Button " + i++);
            b.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            b.setBackground(btn.getBackground());
            ll.addView(b);
        }
    });
    setContentView(ll);
}
}
```

Comment: not gonna lie to ya, Haven't a clue how to integrate that into my activity. A little more information would be helpful, thank you very much for the suggestion and the time out of your day to assist

Comment: wow, thank you very much, need to really go through this and see if i can adapt it to suit my needs, thanks again for your time and assistance